# How to make Selenium webdriver log to file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, log4j

does anyone know how to make Selenium Webdriver log tests results to file? I know log4j, but how to make it write to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which programming language you are using. All language have got a File I/O module. For example, I have been using python, and if you want to port your test results to a file, you can use:

```
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.CRITICAL,
                    format = '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', 
                    datefmt = '%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename = self.testResultRecord,
                    filemode = 'w')
In your tests:
logging.critical("test results 1")
logging.critical("test results 2")
```

Will be written to the file you defined as "self.testResultRecord".

Or alternatively, you can choose one of the test framework from shelf and use them right away, all have been taken care of, you do not need to worry about port results to a file, they will generate a test results for you.

For example, Nose, unittest or robotframework.